# How do I put images and text in the same layout in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uitextview

this is my first post. How can I add text and images to an app. i am only making an image, text and button based app and have made it for android as the picture shows below. I am now trying to do this in iOS but i am unable to place image after text followed by text again.

In android I was able to put multiple ImageView and TextViews inside a scroll layout, but I am unable to do this in storyboard Xcode 4.5/4.6.

If you could give me simple ideas to fix reproduce the same style of layouts in Xcode for iPhone and iPad, it would be great. I am not familiar with Xcode, so if it is possible to solve this easily, could you please help.

I want to be able to make a long scrollable page with many text line and images as you may have already understood from the image below.

Thanks in advance

Sorry was unable to post image. may try again or post website link.

Comment: "image + text" - should it be a button, right?

Comment: you could add multiple UIImageView and add all your subviews within UISCrollView to solve your problem

Comment: Hi, I've tried scrollview and tried to put many text and image views inside but it does not work in the simulator.

Comment: Also, im not attempting to make a button. This isnt allowing me to submit an image otherwise It would be easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to create a UIScrollView -> init UIScrollView with frame and add it to your app, set the content size of your scroll view.
2. Create the UILabel for the text. -> init UILabel with frame and text, add to your scroll view as a subview.
3. Create the UIImageView for the image -> init UIImageView with frame and image, add to your scroll view as a subview.

Typically, that is all if you do it in the way programmatically.

some code (without test):

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 100)];
label1.text = @"label1";
[scrollView addSubview:label1];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 500)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, label1.frame.size.height+imageView.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

ps: If you want do it with nib, I could find some capture for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I did not really understand much of your explanation as I am new to Xcode. I am trying to build it in the new storyboard method as it is easy and does not require any programming (thats what Apple said).

If you could provide a little bit more detail such as where to enter the code or how to do it like any tutorials, videos etc that would help to. Sorry for being overly stupid as I am new to it.

Comment: It's Ok. I have added some code(type directly, without text). Tell me if you still have the question or need more.

Comment: Thanks,Seems to be working better now, now i just need to learn how to use it correctly. Thank you very much. Will try and tick your answer, can vote it up because i'm new